# VLOOKUP multiple times from one row/cell

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I am trying to create a sign-up sheet using Google Forms for parents to fill out. Parents have the ability to sign up multiple children in one form. For it to be easier to read I have organized the entries using:

```
=sort(unique({A2:B999;C2:D999}))
```

Now I want to pull the emergency contact information from the submission but for some reason my VLOOKUP can only pull it up for the first child.

Here is the simplified response sheet: `[goo.gl/soE1PG]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the lookup off to a second [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) with [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) if the first fails.

In I5 as,

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G5, A:E, 5, FALSE), VLOOKUP(G5, C:E, 3, FALSE))
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image: second_vlookup]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!